# Oil Sensor Light on 2002 Audi A4 3.0 Quattro after Oil Change

Tags: oil-change, audi, quattro

Just recently had an Oil Change service done at Brakes Plus (about 4 days ago). I haven't driven it much since, but today I am getting a light on the dash that looks like this:

[image: Oil Sensor Light]

The Check Engine Light is not on, what can I do to diagnose this? I've read that this sensor needs to be disconnected for an oil change. Is it possible they did not connect it back up once they were done?

Comment: It could be a bad fuse. (Red would indicate an issue with oil pressure.)

See this forum post: https://www.audiworld.com/forums/1-8t-discussion-98/flashing-yellow-oil-sensor-light-2684195/

Comment: Certainly worth checking that, thanks @the_storyteller !